# IE9 hiding part of my web page, why?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, popupwindow

I have a web application written in ASP.NET, Framework 4.0.  The web app is 10 years old with a ton of legacy code still existing based on old Framework 2.0. A decision was made to add Telerik RibbonBar controls to the pages and once Telerik was introduced a certain popup browser window has never looked the same. The odd thing is is that the popup was not touched when the RibbonBar control was implemented and no other Telerik controls exist on the popup browser window.

On some machines it still looks fine in IE 8, but on all machines in IE9 the layout gets messed up and it seems as if a portion of the content is being hidden.

The layout utilizes many usercontrols to one aspx page layout with Javascript control of layout.

**The old look and the way this popup browser window is supposed to look is like this:**

[image: Before Telerik update]

**The way that the browser popup window looks currently:**

[image: After Telerik update]

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening in IE9 and not IE8?

***ANSWER (provided by [blachshma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1379664/blachshma)):*** IE=EmulateIE8. It is very specific in what the Emulation says, so IE=8 or IE=Emulate8 will not work, it has to say IE=EmulateIE8

Comment: Can you replicate with a http://jsfiddle.net? (You probably don't want to be publicly displaying real email addresses, even in image form)

Comment: It is a site that is specially designed to allow you to replicate problems with HTML / Javascript / JQuery and a whole load of other technologies, and consequently if you replicate the issue in jsfiddle and then provide the link, we can go in and look directly.  And if appropriate we can also create copies of your jsfiddle to show how to fix issues.  Very useful, totally safe, and regularly utilised across StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you freefaller, I am going to keep that useful

Comment: You're welcome. Another thing on SO, is when replying to comment, you should put the character `@` before their username, that way the user receives a notification. (You will get one for this comment because you created the post the comment is attached to).  And I would STILL recommend you remove the live email addresses on your image!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 is more compliant with W3C standards, which means that certain "features" that were available on previous versions of IE are no longer supported.

You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/18/preparing-your-site-for-ie9.aspx).

To see the specific problems on your website, you can use the [IE9 Compat Inspector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/27/ie9-compat-inspector.aspx)

If you would like IE9 to render your page like IE8 you can use this META tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

Or for IE7

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

Comment: I took a look at the html using f12 of IE9 and when I begin to fiddle with the max-height or height for that matter (taking away the 100% and setting actual pixels  it begins to show the "hidden" elements).

Comment: Well then seems you found a solution... :) Did you try checking/setting the height for the **parent** element? Try using the IE9 Compat Inspector, it  should show you a list of problems...

Comment: I tried setting the heights through debugging in f12. Is there a fix for css wierdness in ie9 to correct this issue, using percentage as that is the requirement. Using a finite pixel height is not a desired thing for the company. (dont know why)

Comment: You haven't mentioned if the code works correctly in other browsers or not... It might be a specific IE9 issue BUT it could be incorrect styling that used to work in older IE versions, but is no longer supported by any browser...

Comment: In any other browser it looks like it is supposed to, it is only in IE that things start getting "hidden"

Comment: Then please post the styles of the elements which are not being shown correctly (and their parent's style) in your question. **Also:** I updated the answer it a META tag you can try using, let me know if this helped

Comment: what would be the easiest way to post the elements? use f12 and get all the styles and simply past them all in here?

Comment: Did you try the META tag I added in my answer?

Comment: BINGO!!! I did have your "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">" in the code but it was set to IE=8, and wasnt working so I took it out. when I used EmulateIE8 it is working now. I am going to try it on the actual production server and see if it works just the same. As some users were reporting it not working in ie8 either

Comment: Great - Lets us know if it fixed the problem or not :)

Comment: Thank you so much Blachshma, sometimes it just takes another set of eyes or mind to point out a simple mistake. It works on production as well.